# I can't select rows from a datetime in a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to get a scope of certain rows in a specific timeframe. The dataframe contains 2 indexes and one of them is made of datetimes (created with pd.to_datetime). When I try to select certain rows using df_pivot.loc[slice(None), '2021'] I get a KeyError: '2021'. Looking for rows using the year should be possible with datetimes right??? What do i do wrong? [picture of the dataframe/indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDyI9.png)

Comment: I also get the keyerror when I use loc and copy in the full datetime (KeyError: '2021-01-01 11:15:00').

Comment: extra info:
I can do this: df_pivot_multi.loc['Woning 268', '2021-1']
i cant do this: df_pivot_multi.loc[['Woning 268', 'Woning 94'], '2021-1']

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved, I used reset_index() and then set_index('Datetime') to make it easier to navigate